# react-native run-ios not Working (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=164)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

While running command "react-native run-ios"
Simulator opens and after BUILD SUCCEEDED I have received message

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/*****.app

An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=164):

Unable to lookup service com.apple.CoreSimulator.host_support: 0x3

Launching app.*****

app.*****: 0

When i run "sudo react-native run-ios"
Simulator doesn't opens and it's looks like every fine but nothing happens. (I tried to open simulator before this still nothing happens)
After BUILD SUCCEEDED i have this message: "
Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/*****.app

Launching app.*****

app.*****: 1055"

Starting project directly from XCode shows this message 
"Unable to lookup service com.apple.CoreSimulator.host_support: 0x3"

node V8.8.1

npm V5.4.2

react-native-cli V2.0.1

react-native V0.47.2

OS MacOs Siera V10.12.6

Watchman V4.9.0

Creating new react-native project not helping and i still have same mistakes.

Comment: After reinstalling XCode and running command without sudo stayed the same, but running with sudo showed new error:  
"An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain, code=4101):
Couldn’t communicate with a helper application."